# How do I build an incinerator that doesn't burn down my house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Usually I have trouble acquiring items, but in 1.11 with a mending fishing rod I'm starting to have a problem I've never had before... too much junk.

So I built a simple incinerator, consisting of a single lava block hidden in my stone floor, with a dropper immediately above it to hide it. This was inset in the wall, and had a button to activate. A little tedious collecting all 80 saddles and 2000 boots (I exaggerate only slightly), put them in, and soon things are back to normal.

That is, until the spontaneous fires occurred. I don't use very many flammable blocks, so it was more shocking than harming, but I wasn't aware that air blocks above lava can catch fire spontaneously even if covered.

How deep do I have to put the lava so that the stone floor doesn't burst into flames? I've got at least 5 or 6 depth that I can use for this.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox No it isn't? It's about lava that is encased in glass/iron/stone affecting nearby wool/other flammables.

Comment: @MageXy, sorry I thought that was a different question

Comment: @John O You could just use a block of cactus instead of fire. Any entity you throw into a cactus will be destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire):

> A fire block can turn any air block that is adjacent to a flammable block into a fire block. This can happen at a distance of up to one block downwards, one block sideways (including diagonals), and four blocks upwards of the original fire block.

So anything 4 blocks underground should be fine.

Also, from plenty of experience in the game, I can assure you that only blocks marked as flammable will ignite. To check this, search for the block on the Minecraft Wiki and look for the flammable tag in the block info.

Comment: I know what I saw. It was a stone brick, lit on fire. Put it out immediately, it was close enough to chests (are those flammable? dunno) that I was worried. Dug up and pailed the lava as soon as my firefighter duties were over.

Comment: A quick look on the Minecraft Wiki shows that chests are, in fact, non-flammable. The fire block would have been adjacent to a flammable block, just look at all the possible candidates on the wiki.

Comment: The only other thing not made of stone/glass was 10 or 12 blocks away, a crafting table. But I saw flames.

Comment: Was it definitely a fire block, and not just an entity on fire?

Comment: Definitely a fire block. Didn't have any entities nearby that could catch on fire. I'd experiment and try to recreate, but I'm on hardcore and hate being risky for dumb stuff. But now you really have me questioning what I saw... there just wasn't anything nearby. Even the closest door was 10 or 12 blocks away.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help any further. If what I've said isn't correct, I don't know what caused the fire. Since you're on hardcore, probably best to ignore. Also, the lava won't ignite anything if it's 4 blocks underground.

Comment: @JohnO How sure are you that it wasn't a burning bat? Those things spawn very quickly, and on Halloween they spawn at much higher light levels.